# Is there a good tutorial on creating a custom plot object - class in python?

Tags: python, plot, graph, graphics

I want to create an object class for custom plotting. I am looking for a good tutorial on object oriented intro for how to create your own plot object ( (possibly still using libraries like matplotlib under the hood)?

E.g.

```
class myplot:
   def __init__(...

   def plotXYZgrpah(...
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you found so far that isn't helping you? There are a lot of matplotlib tutorials out there (and lots of info on the documentation website too).

Comment: I do like matplotlib and I use it often, what I want to do now is to create my own plotting object (possibly using matplotlib under the hood) but which will be specialized for my projects with its own methods and properties...

Comment: You can definitely use matplotlib to build off of. Seaborn did it (another popular plotting package). You'd create a plotting library like you'd create any other library, so start by defining your goals and usage, then head off to implement them.

Comment: Alex L. that is exactly what I am looking to do! I am seeking for an introduction on how to use object oriented approaches to do that.

Comment: Good solution to similar question. Building a custom plotting class on top of matplotlib:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38098026/inherit-from-matplotlib

Comment: I am in your same situation. Did you find a tutorial or a good real working example?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to recommend what you need since I don't know exactly what you need, however I do know that you're interested in making a Python package capable of custom plotting. With that in mind, I think you should have a decent grasp on the basics of the Python language, what a package is and how to make your own, what exactly matplotlib is doing behind the scene, and then go check out some examples.

[Python Textbook](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/) seems useful, especially the chapters on Classes, OOP, and Packaging and Testing

[Python Packaging](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) seems to have a lot on building your own package.

Matplotlib offers [a good overview](https://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html) of what they are capable of doing (to see if this is right for your purposes).

Lastly, there's a lot of examples of packages using matplotlib for more specific plotting. [Check those out](https://github.com/search?l=Python&p=3&q=python%20plot&type=Repositories) to see examples of how others do it. Seaborn is my favorite and I already mentioned it.

---

I wish I could be more specific but this is all I know about your problem! I hope it guides you in the right direction, or at least gives you some vocabulary to make Google searches with!

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in comments the tutorials from [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org) are excellent, you can find a lot of explained examples [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html).

[image: Scatter Masked, Mask some data points and add a line demarking masked regions.]

Based on what you want to learn there are different kinds of tutorials. [This one](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_masked.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-scatter-masked-py), for example, is a good combination if you want to start understanding basic plotting and scattering and create something like in the image above.